# how do I send message from server to client application?

Tags: rest, server, client

My C#, client side, application (in other words a desktop application) currently uses REST calls to send updated category information to the server from behind a firewall.... is it possible for the server to "notify" or "push" information to the application?  (for example when a new category is created )

I don't have any code written yet... I am just wondering if it is possible.. and what objects can be used on the server side / client side to make this "push" event happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use signalr it is part of asp.Net
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Comment: my client side application is NOT a web browser.

Comment: It doesn't have to be you can create hub on any client.                             http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#clientsetup